# How to configure AWS Security Groups to allow HTTP/S access from Avi Vantage, but not from the outside world

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, load-balancing

I've got a website behind Avi Vantage that's suffering from a DDOS attack. I had the web servers in a security group that allowed full HTTP/S access from the outside world, which is where (I think) the DDOS attack was coming from (i.e., not through the VIP).

How do I configure the security group(s) so that the Controller and/or the Service Engine can reach the server via HTTP/S, but the outside world can't reach it?

Comment: Does your Controller and Service Engine have a static IP address or Dynamic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

David,
Setup the SGs associated with the backend servers to allow traffic only from within VPC and optionally your VPC-VPN network if you have one.

**Rule1**
type: All traffic
protocol: All
ports: All
source: 10.20.0.0/16 (VPC-VPN network cidr)

**Rule2**
type: All traffic
protocol: All
ports: All
source: 10.150.0.0/16 (VPC cidr)

Since Avi SEs will be in this VPC, they will allowed by virtue of the rule2. If you needed to directly access your backend servers from your corporate network, you will be allowed by virtue of rule1.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AWS Cloudfront and/or the WAF (Web Application Firewall) to protect your services from the attacks.  Amazon has several blog that details how you can configure your servers to be better protected.

https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx3NVS2JAL7KWOM/How-to-Help-Prepare-for-DDoS-Attacks-by-Reducing-Your-Attack-Surface

https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx1ZTM4DT0HRH0K/How-to-Configure-Rate-Based-Blacklisting-with-AWS-WAF-and-AWS-Lambda

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the info.